# Multy processing with Keras

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I am trying to train a CNN model with Keras using 36 cores that I have. I am trying to follow:
[How to run Keras on multiple cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588383/how-to-run-keras-on-multiple-cores)

But it doesn't make my code faster, and I am not sure whether it uses all the avialble cores or just uses one core, and the rest remains unused.

My code is:

## Model is defined with Keras ==>

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend import tensorflow_backend as K
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
K.set_session(sess)
CNN_Model = CNN_model()

ES = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=150)

history = CNN_Model.fit(IM_Training , Y_Train , batch_size= 256, epochs =250, verbose=1, validation_data=(IM_Valid, Y_Val ), callbacks = [ES])
```

How can I make sure that the code uses all the cores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main ways you can get parallelism when evaluation a neural network:

- Matrix computations
- micro-batch parallelism

The computational graph for many neural networks is sequential (thus Keras having a Sequential model). i.e. one computes layer1 ... layerN in sequence both on forward and backward steps. A sequential network can't be speed up by distributing the layers across different cores.

However most computations use matrix operations which are typically implemented using a high performance lib like BLAS which uses all the cores available to the CPU. Typically the larger the batch size, the larger the opportunities for parallelism.

micro-batch parallelism is the strategy used by [multi_gpu_model](https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model) where different micro-batches are distributed to different compute units (it really makes sense for GPUs primarily).

Non-sequential models can also be parallelised via careful device placement; I'm not sure this is the scenario here. But the TLDR is: increase your batch_size and enjoy all your 36 cores spinning on matrix computations.

Comment: So there is no way to parallelize a sequential Keras network on CPU? It only can be parallelized on GPU via micro-batch parallelism?

Comment: You can parellelize via micro-batch on CPU also. Just that matrix operations are already parallelised so in many instances there is nothing additional to do.Depending on the exact architecture of the network there could be other potential solutions. But sequential networks are sequential and can't be parallelized by assigning different layers to different CPUs / GPUs.