# How to train multiple models time using 4 CPUs and python?

Tags: parallel-processing

My task is like

```py
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor

num = 100
model = dict()

for i in range(100):
    model[i]=GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel,　n_restarts_optimizer=20)

for i in range(num):
    model[i].fit(X,Y)
```

where `X,Y` are my training data constaining features and labels, respectively.

My Ubuntu has 4 CPUs. In order to reduce the training time cost to a quarter of the above code, I therefore want to execute `model[0].fit(X, Y)` on CPU-0, `model[1].fit(X, Y)` on CPU-1, `model[2].fit(X, Y)` on CPU-2 and `model[3].fit(X, Y)` on CPU-3, simultaneously. What should I do?

Comment: What if you divide the range of the loop into 4 groups? E.g. `for i in range(25)`, `for i in range(25,50)`, `for i in range(50,75)` and `for i in range(75, 100)`.

Comment: @Yusufsn Could you please post your （pseudo） code and I would like to run it.

Comment: Use `multiprocessing` module's `pool` and `map` function. The minimal example is at document page.

Comment: perhaps this whould help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588383/how-to-run-keras-on-multiple-cores

Comment: @hunzter I don't find where is that. Can you show me the link? Thanks.

Comment: @hunzter I have been trying using `pool` and `map` since yesterday but make a little progress.

Answer (score -1):

Replace input_x and input_y with your actual training data in a list.

```
input_x=[X for i in range(100)]
input_y=[Y for i in range(100)]

def trainmodel(X,Y):
    model=GaussianProcessRegressor(n_restarts_optimizer=20)
    model.fit(X,Y)
    return model

models=joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=4,verbose=1)(map(joblib.delayed(trainmodel),input_x,input_y))
```

You should also check the number of cpu available just in case

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

Comment: Running the same code in parallel 100 times doesn't do any good if the code isn't actually splitting up the workload between the threads.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Actually you are right. I just read up about it. Its better using loky and multiprocessing.