# Run keras API multiple input/output on multiple cores

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `keras` API with multiple input and output(different shapes). Training takes too much time. So, I need to send every input/output (model) to work in different core(cpu) in parallel. Can I do this in `keras`, and if yes, can you show me how. Below is a simple `keras` code, please help me to send every sub-model to a cpu.

```
# define two sets of inputs
inputA = Input(shape=(32,))
inputB = Input(shape=(128,))

# the first branch operates on the first input
x       = Dense(8, activation="relu")(inputA)
x       = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
outputA = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)

# the second branch opreates on the second input
y        = Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputB)
y        = Dense(32, activation="relu")(y)
outputB  = Dense(16, activation="relu")(y)

# The combined model
model = Model(inputs=[inputA , inputB], outputs=[outputA, outputB])

# Show the models
print(model.summary())

# Build
model.compile(
    loss='mse',
    optimizer='Adam',
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
```

I tried to use Python `Multiprocessing`, but I couldn't actually know how to separate it, or what to send as a function?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588383/how-to-run-keras-on-multiple-cores

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I read this question, but it doesn't really say after creating the session, will every sub-model send to a cpu or how actually this tf.session works